# Using Timelog API in power apps

Tags: api, rest, powerapps

I have a quick question if this is possible or not.

I would like to connect to the Timelog REST API and retrieve worked hours for the week by making use of Power Apps.
[Timelog REST API Doc](https://api.timelog.com/rest)

Has this ever been done before and what are the chances of this actually succeeding ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer--> Yes this can be done.

How-->

- use PowerAutomate
- use this power automate (flow) in your powerapps
- In power automate connect to your API (might need authentication and so on)
- Return the response from your call.
- catch this response in your Powerapps and use it.

[just an example](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-trigger-a-power-automate-flow-from-powerapps/)